# Do not enforce unique title when editing someone else's question

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, title

When editing someone else's question you cannot change the title if one with the same title already exists.

This is annoying when removing e.g. a tag from a title because it doesn't allow you to change it if another question with the new title already exists.

Comment: declining this due to Bill's answer, editing is the perfect time to sort this mess. This is working just as designed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you're editing is exactly the time this sort of thing should be fixed.  If the questions are duplicates, flag them to be closed and merged.  If they're not, please write a more descriptive and specific title.

Comment: I suppose that there is a corner case where it is the *existing* question that really needs a better title, but...yeah, this.

Comment: IMHO even a closed question should have a proper title since it can still be found.

Comment: @dmckee if that's the case, change th existing q's title and then the newer one.

Comment: @Kevin, well sure. But the workflow is awkward.